# How to configure that texstudio run with miktex but lyx run with texlive

Tags: lyx, miktex, texlive, texstudio

I have installed texstudio and miktex first. Then my advisor use lyx so I also download lyx and texlive. However, my texstudio automatically configure with texlive such that some of my previous .tex file can not run.

My question is how to configure the setting such that texstudio is using miktex and lyx using texlive?

My OS is win10.

Comment: there are approximately no documents that give necessarily different results between miktex and texlive. It may be that the two installations that you are using have different versions of one package or another but that could also be the same between two miktex installations or two texlive installations.

Comment: Thank you! I change the \usepackage{natbib} to
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}, then it works. Thank you again!